# Remove an element from the dom when a specific option is selected

Tags: jquery, dom

From this snippet.

```
<div class="form-group row role_id" id="form-group-role">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="form-material">
      <select name="role_id" id="role_id" class="form-control" >           
        <option value="1">Admin</option>
        <option value="2">Writer</option>
      </select>  
      <label for="material-select">Member Type</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tagsinput">
  <select name="place_id" id="place_id" class="form-control" >
    <option value="1">Paris</option>
    <option value="2">Marseille</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

if admin which has the value of 1 is selected I want to remove the tags-input contents from the dom and if 2 then attach it.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#role_id").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()==1){
      $("#tagsinput").hide();
    }else{
      $("#tagsinput").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row role_id" id="form-group-role">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="form-material">
      <select name="role_id" id="role_id" class="form-control" >           
        <option value="1">Admin</option>
        <option value="2">Writer</option>
      </select>  
      <label for="material-select">Member Type</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tagsinput" style="display:none">
  <select name="place_id" id="place_id" class="form-control" >
    <option value="1">Paris</option>
    <option value="2">Marseille</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: People that don't show the slightest attempt to solve their problem shouldn't be encouraged to continue asking bad questions - which your answer does.

Comment: What I want is to remove them from the DOM.